# Python, Kivy, Align TextInput and Button to center of the window

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, boxlayout

I m trying to create a box Layout with canvas which supposed to look like this:

[image: BoxLayout with canvas]
with the following KV language, i m getting something different.

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    IntroScreen:

<IntroScreen>:
    name: 'introscreen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
            spacing: 10
            TextInput:
                id: login
                text: "Login"
                multiline: False
                size_hint_y: 0.5
                size_hint_x: 0.4
                height: 10
                #padding_top: 10
                font_size: 10
            Button:
                text: "Connect"
                on_release: root.current = 'mainpage'
```

Here is the image i m getting: 
[image: Current Result]

Can you please suggest how to modify my kivin language so it look like the first window?

Answer (score 2):

How about the code below. This is using `AnchorLayout`s to align to center and inside the `BoxLayout` to the vertical center as well. It also uses some bindings to determine the text field's height and the button's width.

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    IntroScreen:

<IntroScreen@Screen>:
    name: 'introscreen'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            size_hint: .5, .1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 0
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            spacing: 10
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y': .5}
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                size_hint_x: 1
                TextInput:
                    id: login
                    text: "Login"
                    multiline: False
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_size: 10
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                size_hint_x: None
                Button:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    height: 20
                    width: self.texture_size[0]
                    padding: 10, 10
                    text: "Connect"
                    on_release: root.current = 'mainpage'
```